# Converting nlm() call to nlminb() call

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I have some legacy code that does nonlinear optimization with `nlm()`.  I am intending to update the code to `nlminb()` so that constrained optimization is possible.  I understand that the methods might not be identical or equivalent, but given the following arguments supplied to `nlm()`, what is the call and arguments supplied for a similar call to `nlminb` ?

```
##' @param print.level Arguments for nlm.
##' @param typsize Arguments for nlm.
##' @param ndigit Arguments for nlm.
##' @param gradtol Arguments for nlm.
##' @param stepmax Arguments for nlm.
##' @param steptol Arguments for nlm.
##' @param iterlim Arguments for nlm.
##' @param fscale Arguments for nlm.


# Take the legacy nlm() call and ...    
z0 <- nlm(like,p=p,hessian=TRUE,print.level=print.level,typsize=typsize,
    ndigit=ndigit,gradtol=gradtol,stepmax=stepmax,steptol=steptol,
    iterlim=iterlim,fscale=fscale)


# turn into nlminb call:
z0 <- nlminb(nlminb args with different names but taking same @param from parent function)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem!  I'm ultimately going to suggest using `optimx` ( [Rdocs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/optimx) and [JSS site](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v043i09)), but for now let's map `nlm` over `nlminb`.

I'll touch up what you wrote:

```
##' @param print.level Arguments for nlm.
##' @param typsize Arguments for nlm.
##' @param ndigit Arguments for nlm.
##' @param gradtol Arguments for nlm.
##' @param stepmax Arguments for nlm.
##' @param steptol Arguments for nlm.
##' @param iterlim Arguments for nlm.
##' @param fscale Arguments for nlm.


# Take the legacy nlm() call and ...    
z0 <- nlm(f=like,
          p=p,
          hessian=TRUE,
          print.level=print.level,
          typsize=typsize,
          ndigit=ndigit,
          gradtol=gradtol,
          stepmax=stepmax,
          steptol=steptol,
          iterlim=iterlim,
          fscale=fscale
          )
```

A similar call in `nlminb()` will look like below.  First thing we note is that `nlminb()` uses a `control` argument with `control parameters`, as well as arguments `objective` and `start` as opposed to `f` and `p` (respectively; and in different order than `nlm` so be sure to explicitly type arguments):

```
# turn into nlminb call:
z0 <- nlminb(objective=like,
             start=p,
             hessian=TRUE,
             control = list(trace=print.level,  #for 0, same behavior
                            #typsize=typsize,
                            #ndigit=ndigit,
                            #gradtol=gradtol,
                            step.max=stepmax,
                            #steptol=steptol,
                            iter.max=iterlim,
                            #fscale=fscale
             )
)
```

I'd recommend adding more arguments to parent function and using `optimx`:

```
##' @param print.level Arguments for nlm.
##' @param typsize Arguments for nlm.
##' @param ndigit Arguments for nlm.
##' @param gradtol Arguments for nlm.
##' @param stepmax Arguments for nlm, nlminb
##' @param steptol Arguments for nlm.
##' @param iterlim Arguments for optimx, nlm, nlminb
##' @param fscale Arguments for nlm.
##' @param trace Arguments for nlminb
##' @param method Argument for optimx

z0 <- optimx(fn=like, 
             par=p, 
             hessian=TRUE, ## not `hess`
             method=c("nlminb"), 
             itnmax=iterlim, 
             control = list(
               # for nlm:
               print.level=print.level,
               typsize=typsize,
               ndigit=ndigit,
               gradtol=gradtol,
               stepmax=stepmax,
               steptol=steptol,
               #iterlim=iterlim, # preferred as itnmax above
               fscale=fscale,
               # for nlminb:
               trace=trace,
               step.max=stepmax
               # ... any other nlminb args
             )             
)
```

And to get the hessian extracted out of `optimx` do:

```
## hessian extraction (1st row or by name):
attr(fit, "details")[1,]$nhatend
attr(fit, "details")["nlminb",]$nhatend
```

**Below is not necessary for the problem, but just puts the `nlm` arguments of interest in one place and then comes to conclusion that there isn't a perfect 1-to-1 match for `nlminb`**

Below are the `nlm()` argument definitions for `print.level`, `typsize`, `ndigit`, `gradtol`, `stepmax`, `steptol`, `iterlim`, and `fscale` for `nlm()` (pulled from [Rdocs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/nlm)):

- `print.level`  this argument determines the level of printing which is done during the minimization process. The default value of 0 means that no printing occurs, a value of 1 means that initial and final details are printed and a value of 2 means that full tracing information is printed.
- `typsize` an estimate of the size of each parameter at the minimum.
- `ndigit` the number of significant digits in the function `f`.
- `gradtol` a positive scalar giving the tolerance at which the scaled gradient is considered close enough to zero to terminate the algorithm. The scaled gradient is a measure of the relative change in f in each direction p[i] divided by the relative change in p[i].
- `stepmax` a positive scalar which gives the maximum allowable scaled step length. `stepmax` is used to prevent steps which would cause the optimization function to overflow, to prevent the algorithm from leaving the area of interest in parameter space, or to detect divergence in the algorithm. `stepmax` would be chosen small enough to prevent the first two of these occurrences, but should be larger than any anticipated reasonable step.
- `steptol` A positive scalar providing the minimum allowable relative step length.
- `iterlim`  a positive integer specifying the maximum number of iterations to be performed before the program is terminated.
- `fscale` an estimate of the size of f at the minimum.

Now we try to find matches in `nlminb()` (pulled from [Rdocs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/nlminb)).  First thing we note is that `nlminb()` uses a `control` argument with `control parameters`:

```
# turn into nlminb call:
z0 <- nlminb(objective=like,
             start=p,
             hessian=TRUE,
             control = list(trace=print.level,  #for 0, same behavior
                            #typsize=typsize,
                            #ndigit=ndigit,
                            #gradtol=gradtol,
                            step.max=stepmax,
                            #steptol=steptol,
                            iter.max=iterlim,
                            #fscale=fscale
             )
)
```

The closest thing to `nlm`'s `print.level` is probably `trace`.  For a value of 0, both do the same thing.  However, for nonzero values they operate differently.

- `trace`  The value of the objective function and the parameters is printed every `trace`'th iteration. Defaults to 0 which indicates no trace information is to be printed.

**Conclusion:  And looking more into the documentation it looks like coming up with an exact match could be challenging.  That's why I punted and recommended expanding parent arguments and using optimx.**